# VSCode Jupyter, everything is dark except plots

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm running the JupyterDash example and it looks like this:

[image: jupyterdashexample]

The title "JupyterDash Demo" and the white background of the page that is supposed to run is too dark that I can barely see it.  I also have the same problem with my own example.

Is there a fix for this?